# \left and \right not working in multiple line equation

Tags: errors, equations

I want to recreate the following:

[image]

What I have is this:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\nabla f(x_i) = \nabla f(x_i, y_j, z_k) & \approx ( \dfrac{1}{2} \left( f(x_{i+1}, y_j, z_k) - f(x_{i-1}, y_j, z_k) \right), \\
 & \phantom{abc} \dfrac{1}{2} \left( f(x_{i}, y_{j+1}, z_k) - f(x_{i}, y_{j-1}, z_k) \right), \\
  & \phantom{abc} \dfrac{1}{2} \left( f(x_{i}, y_j, z_{k+1}) - f(x_{i}, y_j, z_{k-1}) \right) )
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

When I try to change the size of the first and last bracket with \left and \right I get an error. How else could I adjust the sizes of the first and last bracket?

Comment: `\left( ... \right)` doesn't work over ampersands and multi lines equations. instead it you need to use `\bigl(` or `\biggl(` etc braces, or closed each line with `\right.` however, this not guaranty that the left and right parenthesis will have the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\right.` and `\left.`. LaTeX only processes the `\left`s and `\right`s in a given equation line. That is, you need to have as many `\left`s as `\right`s per line. In this sense, LaTeX is very different from the parliaments of this planet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
\nabla f(x_i) = \nabla f(x_i, y_j, z_k) & \approx \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \left( f(x_{i+1}, y_j, z_k) - f(x_{i-1}, y_j, z_k) \right)
\right., \\
 & \phantom{abc} \dfrac{1}{2} \left( f(x_{i}, y_{j+1}, z_k) - f(x_{i}, y_{j-1}, z_k) \right), \\
  & \phantom{abc}\left. \dfrac{1}{2} \left( f(x_{i}, y_j, z_{k+1}) - f(x_{i},
  y_j, z_{k-1}) \right) \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```